# Why do I get "unexpected CID" error when adding a static image to a php mailing system?

Tags: php, email, mime

So using `MIME`, i have created a php mail system but can't seem to fix one problem with an attached header image I want at the top of the email.

The code I am using results in the following error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'cid' (T_STRING) in W:\xampp\htdocs\website1\show_notifications_to_send.php on line 152
```

The Code I am using is in this block is as follows:

```
$headers =  "Content-Type: "
            $headers = "From: admin@____.com\n"; //left out email
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Location: CID:website1\img_004.jpg ; //Changed URLs slightly
            $headers .= "Content-ID: <img_004.jpg>";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: IMAGE/GIF";
            $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64";
            $fullImportStatusMessage="<style>body{font-size: 12px;color:#666;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;}table{border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;padding: 6px 24px;}</style><html><body> <IMG SRC="cid:img_004.jpg" ALT="IETF logo"> .$updatedEmailText.</body></html>"; //This is the line with error
        $dryrun=false;
```

I can add up more code but I think the problem is in this. Thanks for any tips & suggestions
edit: I see I am downvoted so sorry if I've been asking my questions wrong. I'll review the rules

Comment: There's a double quote missing on the fourth header. And why are there two `Content-Type:` headers?

Comment: That double quote is actually there in the code, I just messed up copying it over, I'll edit it now. Thanks for showing me it. As for having 2 content headers Ill check it out. I just did what a tutorial told me to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$fullImportStatusMessage="<style>body{font-size: 12px;color:#666;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;}table{border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;padding: 6px 24px;}</style><html><body> <IMG SRC="cid:img_004.jpg" ALT="IETF logo"> .$updatedEmailText.</body></html>"; //This is the line with error
```

should be:

```
$fullImportStatusMessage='<style>body{font-size: 12px;color:#666;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;}table{border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;padding: 6px 24px;}</style><html><body> <IMG SRC="cid:img_004.jpg" ALT="IETF logo">'
  . $updatedEmailText
  . '</body></html>'; //This is the line with error
```

Note the changes to the outer quote characters. You already have double quotes embedded in the string, so you either have to use single quotes to delimit the string *or* escape the double quotes using backslash (`\"`).